# How to perform slicing of a data frame using datetimes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` `df1`, indexed with a `pandas.DateRange` object.

If I have a `d1` and `d2`, as datetimes, why does `df[d1:d2]`not work, and how can I obtain this slice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
In [25]: df.ix[d1:d2]
Out[25]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-10  1.149815  0.686696 -1.230991 -1.610557
2000-01-11 -1.296118 -0.172950 -0.603887  0.383690
2000-01-12 -1.034574 -0.523238  0.626968  0.471755
2000-01-13 -0.193280  1.857499 -0.046383  0.849935
2000-01-14 -1.043492 -0.820525  0.868685 -0.773050
2000-01-17 -1.622019 -0.363992  1.207590  0.577290
```

cf. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-labels

On first principles `df[d1:d2]` should work as it does for Series:

```
In [27]: df['A'][d1:d2]
Out[27]: 
2000-01-10    1.149815
2000-01-11   -1.296118
2000-01-12   -1.034574
2000-01-13   -0.193280
2000-01-14   -1.043492
2000-01-17   -1.622019
Name: A
```

Creating an issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/946

Answer (score 7):

Try the [**`truncate`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html) method:

```
df.truncate(before=d1, after=d2)
```

It won't modify your original `df` and will return a truncated one.

From docs:

```
Function truncate a sorted DataFrame / Series before and/or after
some particular dates.

Parameters
----------
before : date
    Truncate before date
after : date
    Truncate after date

Returns
-------
truncated : type of caller
```

Comment: Can you link to a source for this? I'm on http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#daterange-is-a-valid-index and I haven't found the truncate function.

Comment: It works, thanks.  Is there a reason why the more convenient `df[d1:d2]` doesnt work?

Comment: @Paragon: here's the link to the description of truncate in the current documentation (v0.7.2): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html?highlight=truncate#pandas.DataFrame.truncate

Comment: @saroele no reason, just an API oversight. See my answer below-- if someone would contribute some docs about truncate that would be helpful.

Comment: @saroele - I believe `df[d1:d2]` would imply, that both `d1` and `d2` are contained in the index (just like in lists). `before/after` doesn't sound that restrictive.